# Is there a simpler way to do string_match from CodingBat in Python?

Tags: python, logic

This is the problem. http://codingbat.com/prob/p182414

To summarize, given two strings (a and b) return how many times a substring of 2, from string a is in string b. For example, string_match('xxcaazz', 'xxbaaz') → 3.

```
def string_match(a, b):
    amount = 0
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if (len(a[i:i+2]) == 2) and a[i:i+2]  == b[i:i+2]:
            amount += 1
    return amount
```

Comment: Are you claiming that string_match('ab','aabaaba') returns 2?

Comment: @ScottHunter Yea, just realized that example doesn't work. Added a new example.

Comment: You don't iterate over `b` separately to `a`.

Comment: Your code doesn't work for the new example, either, at least in part for the reason @PeterWood.

Comment: @ScottHunter The new example for working for me. I get 3 when I run it.

Comment: Aha -- your "summary" implies that the substrings don't need to be at the same offset in the two strings.

Comment: @ScottHunter My bad.

Comment: @GregoryDolan my bad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not much simpler, but if you limit the range of `i` to `len(a)-1`, you don't need to check if it defines a long enough substring of `a`.

Comment: Thanks. This was more or less what I was looking for as the logic statement I have, is a little ugly.

Answer (score 0):

My approach is something like this:

```
def string_match(a, b):
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(a)-1):
        if a[i:i+2]==b[i:i+2]:
            count += 1
    return count
```